# Mapbox not full-screen/height on Modal open with Alpine JS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, alpine.js

```js
export const Mapbox = ({ data = [] }) => ({
    init() {
        let geojson = [];

        data.map((item) => {
            // Here we will fill the geojson array with the data we got from Data prop
            geojson.push({
                type: "Feature",
                geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: [item.longitude, item.latitude],
                },
                properties: {
                    price: item.price,
                    title: item.title,
                    address: item.address,
                    url: item.url,
                    featured_image: item.featured_image,
                },
            });
        });

        var monument = [20.9144, 41.7895];
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: "map",
            style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10",
            center: monument,
            zoom: 15,
        });

        // Disabling 3D
        map.dragRotate.disable();
        map.touchZoomRotate.disableRotation();
        map.resize();

        // Add markers to map
        for (const feature of geojson) {
            const el = document.createElement("div");
            el.className = "marker";

            el.style.color = "#fff";
            el.style.fontSize = "16px";
            el.innerHTML = feature.properties.price; // Here we add price

            new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
                .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
                .setPopup(
                    new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // Add popups
                        .setHTML(
                            `
                            <a href="${feature.properties.url}"
                                class="flex flex-col w-full duration-200 ease-in-out border rounded-2xl border-dark-100 hover:border-brand-950 hover:ring-1 hover:ring-brand-950">
                                <div class="shrink-0 rounded-t-2xl overflow-hidden">
                                    <img src="${feature.properties.featured_image}" class="object-cover w-full h-48" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="relative flex flex-col justify-between flex-1 p-4 bg-white rounded-b-2xl">
                                    <div class="flex-1">
                                        <p class="font-bold font-satoshi [&>i]:font-boska [&>i]:font-medium text-xl   text-brand-800">
                                            ${feature.properties.price}
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="font-bold font-satoshi [&>i]:font-boska [&>i]:font-medium text-lg leading-8 text-dark-950 mb-2">
                                            ${feature.properties.title}
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="font-cabinet text-base leading-[24px] text-dark-950 font-light">
                                            ${feature.properties.address}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            `
                        )
                )
                .addTo(map);
        }
    },
});

export default Mapbox;
```

This is my code for the Mapbox ^

Below is my html:

```html
<div class="flex items-center justify-center mt-16">
    {{ partial:components/modal }}
        {{ slot:header }}
            <div class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                {{ svg src="map-icon" class="w-6 h-6 shrink-0" }}
                <x-text color="blue" weight="700">
                    Show Map
                </x-text>
            </div>
        {{ /slot:header }}

        {{# Map Modal #}}
        <div x-data="mapbox({ data:
            [
                {{ properties }}
                    {
                        url: '{{ url }}',
                        featured_image: '{{ featured_image }}',
                        title: '{{ title }}',
                        price: '{{ price }}',
                        address: '{{ address }}',
                        propety_features: {{ property_features | to_json | entities }},
                        content: {{ content | to_json | entities }},
                        latitude: '{{ latitude }}',
                        longitude: '{{ longitude }}',
                    },
                {{ /properties }}
            ]})">
            <div id="map" class="overflow-hidden rounded-2xl"></div>
        </div>
    {{ /partial:components/modal }}
</div>
```

and CSS:

```css
/* Mapbox */
#map {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 650px;
    width: 95%;
}
.marker {
    background-color: #0F68FF;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.mapboxgl-popup {
    max-width: 200px;
}
.mapboxgl-popup-content {
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 16px;
}
.mapboxgl-popup-close-button
{
    background-color: #E7F0FF;
    padding: 0px 7px 2px 7px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 12px;
    right: 12px;
}
.alpine {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

When I initialy click on the Modal, it opens up the map but with it's default 400x300 width and height, when I resize the window (aka open the chrome web tools or w/e, it fixes itself, but I want the map to load full screen and height in initial state, help)

Here's some screenshots on initial modal open and after opening up chrome web tools

[before resizing manually screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpNte.png)

[after resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geU8T.png)

Comment: What does it set the 300px width to? A child div of the `#map`? If so, can't you force 100% width with CSS?